# Excluding a JPA entity from Hibernate persistenceContext caching?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm building a web-app with Spring, and JPA backed by Hibernate 4.3.6 for persistence. Some background: job results are being stored in a repository, and a ResultsController checks on them. The front-end uses long polling, so the ResultsController creates a DeferredResult object and then spins off a thread to check periodically for completion of the job so that it can fill in the deferred result and trigger the response.

```
private DeferredResultsResponse getResults(String idString, String runType, boolean returnOnNotDone) {
    String userId = userService.getCurrentUser();

    // Some basic checks; is the ID a valid format, etc. Not relevant,
    // but the "response" variable is set if we find a problem

    final DeferredResultsResponse deferredResult = new DeferredResultsResponse(runId, runType, userId, returnOnNotDone);
    if (response != null) {
        deferredResult.setResult(response);
    } else {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> completeResult(deferredResult));
        t.run();
    }

    return deferredResult;
}

private void completeResult(final DeferredResultsResponse result) {
    final ResultsIdentifier id = new ResultsIdentifier(result.getJobId(), result.getRunType());
    int attemptCount = 0;
    boolean returnOnUnfinished = result.isReturnOnUnfinished();

    while (!result.hasResult() && attemptCount < MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
        attemptCount++;
 // ------- Problem line: -----------
        Optional<JobStatus> statusMaybe = jobStatusService.get(new ResultsIdentifier(result.getJobId(), result.getRunType()));

        if (!statusMaybe.isPresent()) {
            result.setResult(new ResultsResponse(null, false, null, "Unable to find job status entry."));
            continue;
        }

        JobStatus status = statusMaybe.get();
        // Incomplete job cases: sleep or respond "not done" based on the flag
        if (!status.isComplete() && returnOnUnfinished) {
            result.setResult(new ResultsResponse(false, false, null, null));
            continue;
        } else if (!status.isComplete()) {
            sleep();
            continue;
        }

        // Cases of completion: respond based on success
        // Various business logic of processing results
    }
    if (!result.hasResult()) {
        result.setResult(new ResultsResponse(true, false, null, String.format("Time out after %d checks", MAX_ATTEMPTS)));
    }
}
```

**The issue is this**: the query on the Problem Line doesn't ever report changes in the job's status. After some looking, I tracked this down to the innards of Hibernate. In SessionImpl there is a field of type StatefulPersistenceContext, and it is keeping a copy of the JobStatus object from the first time it's pulled out of the database. It then reuses that copy on all subsequent queries in the same session.

Now, I gather that I can solve this by getting the current session and calling clear(), or refresh(status). However, to me, having to pull back the JPA curtain and use Hibernate stuff directly when everywhere else it's mediated through the Spring/JPA repositories is bad form. So, is there any way to mark up an ORM XML file to exclude a particular type from being cached in the PersistanceContext?

---

For reference, here is JobStatus.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
<entity class="project.model.JobStatus">
<attributes>
  <embedded-id name="jobIdentifier" />

  <basic name="complete" optional="false" />
  <basic name="userId" optional="false" />

  <basic name="successful" optional="true" />
  <basic name="message" optional="true" />

  <basic name="lastUpdateTime" optional="false">
    <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
  </basic>
</attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

jobIdentifier is an  which contains nothing but the single  element with no children.

Also, here is the JobStatusService with transaction annotations:

```
public interface JobStatusService {

/**
 * Retrieve the statuses of all jobs for the current user.
 * @return All jobs' statuses
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Iterable<JobStatus> getAllByUser();

/**
 * Retrieve the status of a particular job
 * @param identifier the combined job ID and type
 * @return  The persisted job status
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
Optional<JobStatus> get(ResultsIdentifier identifier);

/**
 * Save the passed status, subbing in the current user's ID if none is set,
 * and updating the "last updated" time
 * @param status the job status object
 * @return  The persisted status object
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Modifying
JobStatus save(JobStatus status);

/**
 * Delete the status of a particular job
 * @param identifier the combined job ID and type
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Modifying
void remove(ResultsIdentifier identifier);

/**
 * Remove all stored job statuses for the given user id.
 * @param userId User id
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Modifying
void clearByUser(String userId);
```

Comment: FWIW that is no "hbm" file. It is an "orm.xml", part of JPA.

Comment: True! Sorry, the guy that started the project initially named them all *.hbm.xml and I've not bothered to change the names despite it being right there in the xmlns.

Answer (score 2):

> the ResultsController creates a DeferredResult object and then spins off a thread

Actually, no, that's not what it does. You never start the thread. You're executing everything in the same thread, and you only return the deferred result once `completeResult()` has returned. To really start a thread, you would have to replace

```
t.run();
```

by

```
t.start();
```

Now, to make sure the problem line always goes to the database and reloads the new value of the job status,what you should do is to make sure that `jobStatusService.get()` runs in a separate transaction. Using Spring, that is typically done by annotating the method with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Comment: I gave this a try, and it doesn't seem to work, nor does Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED which sounded promising as well. (Anything to invalidate/clear/change sessions!) Added JobStatusService to the OP in case other annotations are interacting badly to make your suggestion fail. Also, after correcting the threading error (thanks for spotting that!) I found that `completeResult()` started throwing exceptions about not having a session at all. So in order to pass on the session to that thread, I might have to suck it up and make the controller know about Hibernate sessions anyway.

Comment: I do have a feeling I'm fundamentally missing something (both on the persistence, and the asynch result completion--I never got `@Async` to work right), but it's surprisingly hard to find good documentation about the way that Spring interacts between its frameworks, and with other frameworks it can tie to.

Comment: The session typically has the same life-cycle as the spring transaction. And the transaction status is stored by Spring in a ThreadLocal variable. So starting a thread that calls a transactional service should start a new Spring transaction, and that should cause a new Session to be bound to the transaction. It's hard to say why this doesn't work in your tests.

Comment: Well, it's certainly the best lead I have so far, so I'll start the process of delving into the proxy code that actually interprets the annotations and hopefully something will present itself. Thanks!