# Changing fetch to EAGER seems to fix unrelated session caching problems

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

This isn't a "it's broken" question. It's a *why isn't it broken?!* question. Unfortunately there's a bit of context required.

I asked [a question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505231/excluding-a-jpa-entity-from-hibernate-persistencecontext-caching) about how I wanted to override Hibernate's first-level caching in order to get a newly-updated JobStatus entity's data instead of the cached (but stale) version. I got two useful comments: first, I should try `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the service method; second, in an attempt to spin off a thread to process something, I'd called `thread.run()` instead of `thread.start()` which runs the code but on the same thread.

Applying these suggestions, I found that `REQUIRES_NEW` didn't seem to do anything, and `thread.start()` yielded `ERROR: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: DataSourceResults`

Now, as an experiment, I changed the loading of a collection field in DataSourceResults to `EAGER`. Not only did this fix the LazyInitializationException, but it also fixed the stale session-cache problem, even though that's a *totally different entity type*, JobStatus. My question, essentially, is:

How can this possibly be?

For reference: ORM XML for the entities involved.

```
<entity class="semantica.bsx.model.datasource.DataSourceResults">
<attributes>
  <embedded-id name="resultsIdentifier" />
  <basic name="dataSourceId" optional="false"/>
  <basic name="serviceUrl" optional="true" />
  <!--basic name="userId" optional="false"/-->

  <one-to-many name="resultList" target-entity="model.datasource.DataSourceResult" orphan-removal="true" fetch="EAGER">
    <cascade><cascade-all/></cascade>
  </one-to-many>

  <!-- Adding EAGER to the next line fixed everything... how?! -->
  <element-collection name="fieldNames" fetch="EAGER">
    <map-key-column name="fieldKey"/>
    <column name="fieldLabels"/>
  </element-collection>

</attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="model.datasource.DataSourceResult">
<attributes>
  <id name="id">
    <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
  </id>
  <element-collection name="fieldValues" fetch="EAGER">
    <map-key-column name="fieldValueKey"/>
      <column length="20000"></column>
    <!--<column name="fieldValue" length="1000000000"/>-->
      <!--<lob/>-->
  </element-collection>
</attributes>
```

```
<entity class="model.JobStatus">
<attributes>
  <embedded-id name="jobIdentifier" />

  <basic name="complete" optional="false" />
  <basic name="userId" optional="false" />

  <basic name="successful" optional="true" />
  <basic name="message" optional="true" />

  <basic name="lastUpdateTime" optional="false">
    <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
  </basic>
</attributes>
```

Comment: PS: if you can enlighten me on this, feel free to go back to the linked question or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639424/propagation-requires-new-seems-to-not-work and post an answer there, and I'll accept it.